# Update sql table columns with data from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
UPDATE [APL4_WATERPLANT].[dbo].[PRINT_PWD] 
SET [APL4_WATERPLANT].[dbo].[PRINT_PWD].[CLT_2101] = ([APL4_WATERPLANT].[dbo].[PWD].[CLT_2101] 
FROM [APL4_WATERPLANT].[dbo].[PWD] 
WHERE [APL4_WATERPLANT].[dbo].[PWD].[DATEANDTIME] = '2013-8-13 12:00:00.000')
```

Whenever i try to execute this code, i get a error message. what could be the problem ?

Comment: Your syntaxt is wrong. Check out this MSDN article: http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177523.aspx

Comment: IN Subquery you need SELECT statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 UPDATE [APL4_WATERPLANT].[dbo].[PRINT_PWD] 
 SET [APL4_WATERPLANT].[dbo].[PRINT_PWD].[CLT_2101] = (select CLT_2101 
 FROM [APL4_WATERPLANT].[dbo].[PWD] 
 WHERE DATEANDTIME = '2013-8-13 12:00:00.000')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think select is missing from the subquery:-

```
UPDATE    [APL4_WATERPLANT].[dbo].[PRINT_PWD] 
SET       [APL4_WATERPLANT].[dbo].[PRINT_PWD].[CLT_2101] = 
          (
              select  [APL4_WATERPLANT].[dbo].[PWD].[CLT_2101] 
              FROM    [APL4_WATERPLANT].[dbo].[PWD] 
              WHERE   [APL4_WATERPLANT].[dbo].[PWD].[DATEANDTIME] = '2013-8-13 12:00:00.000'
          )
```